# pytest execute code before database created

Tags: django, pytest

In `AdminForm` I prevent the user from duplicating the records.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from apps.accounting_users.models import AccountingUser
from apps.marketing_users.models import MarketingUser
from apps.mgmt_users.models import ManagementUser
from apps.serv_mgrs_users.models import ServiceMgmtUser
from apps.serv_staff_users.models import ServiceStaffUser


class BaseDjangoAdminRoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.exclude(
            username__in=[record.user.username for record in AccountingUser.objects.all()] +
                         [record.user.username for record in MarketingUser.objects.all()] +
                         [record.user.username for record in ManagementUser.objects.all()] +
                         [record.user.username for record in ServiceMgmtUser.objects.all()] +
                         [record.user.username for record in ServiceStaffUser.objects.all()],
        )
    )
```

**mgmt_users/models.py**

```
from apps.commons.models import AbstractSBrandUser


class ManagementUser(AbstractSBrandUser):
    pass
```

**commons/models**

```
class AbstractSBrandUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

OSX 10.12.4 pytest is normal
Debian:Jessie is broken

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/buddy/siam-sbrand/portal/apps/mgmt_users/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apps.commons.forms import BaseDjangoAdminRoleForm
  File "/buddy/siam-sbrand/portal/apps/commons/forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    class BaseDjangoAdminRoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/buddy/siam-sbrand/portal/apps/commons/forms.py", line 17, in BaseDjangoAdminRoleForm
    [record.user.username for record in ServiceMgmtUser.objects.all()] +
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
```

**Question:**
I had checked the syntax based on `python3` already.
And I had checked the `filter` syntax of `Django1.10` already.
`python manage.py shell` run fine. No error at all.

How can I use queryset in the `AdminForm` of the Django and pass the test?
Do I need to sacrify testing for this feature?

Comment: Did you try to prepopulate test database before testing?

Comment: yes, I have `conftest.py` and they contain multple function with `@pytest.fixture`

Comment: But they never be a problem since I add `AdminForm` with `queryset`. If I set it to `User.objects.all()`. pytest is ok. Any idea?

Comment: When you run tests django creates new empty database. You need to populate it in test. In your case User.objects.all() returns nothing. I never worked with Pytest(therefore I dont know what pytest is doing with fixtures) but I worked with Django and I also had problems due to empty test database.

Comment: I have test and I have to call `fixture` to test all of my APIs. This time it is not an APIs it is `AdminForm` I have no any test caes on this kind. Then am totally blank why queryset raises an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use querysets like `[record.user.username for record in AccountingUser.objects.all()]` in your model form definition. Django tries to evaluate the queryset when the module is loaded. If the table has not been created yet, this will give an error.

You can fix the problem by setting the queryset in the `__init__` method.

```
class BaseDjangoAdminRoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseDjangoAdminRoleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(...)
```

This has the advantage of evaluating the usernames every time the form is created - at the moment, they are only evaluated once when the server starts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never known this sort of technique. How do you know this solution? What topic I can prevent this bug in the future?

Comment: Setting querysets in the `__init__` method is a pretty common technique, I'm not sure where I learned it. You can avoid errors like this by making sure that you do not perform any database queries at module level. That means moving querysets into view/form methods.

Comment: I am very new to the `form`. Let me confirm my understanding `module level` is the class property. Then I put queryset under `__init__` is mean object level. Am I correct?

Comment: Thank you very much